# How can I export data from a UITableView to Excel?

Tags: iphone, excel, uitableview

I am new to iPhone development. I have one form that displays data on a `UITableView` (about 60-70 records). Now I want to export this data to an Excel spreadsheet.

I don't understand how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is not write my code for me site!

Comment: @Nick: By definition, those people are *not* helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest some reading on [Comma separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Excel, Numbers or OpenOffice can read that format easily. It should also be easy for you to generate that format in iOS.

Comment: Yes, CSV is a good solution for non-formatted, simple tables. Easy to implement